# Facebook like button failed, as web page declared unsafe

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I've tried to implement the facebook like button on my web page. I copied code from the fb developer page:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="www.xy.com" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

But when I click like button, I got this error message:

*The content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe:Body of an error/warning message. Title is: You can't post this because it has a blocked linkPlease remove this link to continue.*

Is there anything I could do?